# handle click on a moving animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, mouseevent

I have a button with ripple effect. That button have mouseUp, mouseDown and onClick handlers.
And when i click on a button ripple effect starts and everything is ok.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGEF3.png)

But when i click again, while ripple is still moving (on the area of a ripple), only mouseUp and mouseDown trigger (onClick doesn't). Is that ok?

Thank you.

Code source: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-fast-d42xp?file=/src/RippleButton/index.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add in CSS `pointer-events: none;` to your `.ripple`.
The *ripple* does not need any pointer events since it's simply used for animation effect purpose.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I didn't know there is such property